# opening JFrame from applet

Tags: java, swing, applet, jframe, awt

So I programmed am applet that makes a ball roll in circles for ever, and I wanted to make the user decide what speed the circle should roll in, but something failed when I added the JFrame:

applet(the stop,destroy and update do not appear because they aren't important, and in start there is nothing):

```
public class Main extends Applet implements Runnable{

private Image I;
private Graphics GfU;
int ballX, ballY=249;
static int radius=20;
double Memory;
int changeY ,changeX=1;
Speed S = new Speed();

@Override
public void init() {
    setSize(750,750);
    S.setVisible(true);
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while(true){
        if(ballY>=250 || ballY<=-250){
            changeY=0-changeY;
            changeX=0-changeX;
        }
        ballY+=changeY;
        Memory=(double)ballY/250; 
        Memory=Math.asin(Memory);
        Memory=Math.cos(Memory);
        ballX=(int)(Memory*250);
        if(changeX==-1)
            ballX=0-ballX;

        repaint();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(17);            
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }
}



@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.fillOval(ballX-radius+250, ballY-radius+250, radius*2, radius*2);
}


public void setChangeY(int changeY) {
    this.changeY = changeY;
}

public void Done(){
    S.setVisible(false);
    Thread BallRun = new Thread(this);
    BallRun.start();
}

}
```

JFrame:

```
public class Speed extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public Speed(){
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel P = new JPanel();
    JLabel L = new JLabel("please enter velosity(pixels per second)");
    final JTextField TF = new JTextField("00");
    final Main M = new Main();
    JButton B = new JButton("OK");

    B.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            M.setChangeY(Integer.parseInt(TF.getText()));
            M.Done();

        }
    });

    P.add(L,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    P.add(TF,BorderLayout.WEST);

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {


}
}
```

thanks (and sorry if it's bothering you the lack of information)

Answer (score 1):

Here are some things to consider:

1. Don't use a JFrame. Use a JDialog as a popup window. Also, you should probably not create the dialog in the constructor. Instead you should have a JMenuItem so that the user can click on the menu when they want the popup to display.
2. Don't use "Applet", that is an AWT component. You should be using "JApplet" in a Swing application.
3. You should not be overriding the paint() method of the applet. Instead you should be adding a JPanel to the applet and then override the paintComponent(...) with your custom painting.
4. Don't use a loop to control the animation. Instead you should be using a Swing Timer.

Start by reading the [Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html). There are sections on:

1. How to Make Applets
2. How to Use Swing Timers
3. Performing Custom Painting

Comment: thanks, but I don't really understand half the things you wrote, but I will look into those things.
And JApplet is like better Applet, right?

Comment: `JApplet` is better in your project because you have to interact with swing components like `JFrame`, and `JApplet` is a swing component.

Comment: thank you, I will look into it.
And last question, are there situations in  which `Applet` is better than `JApplet`?

Comment: We can say that is better if you use `Applet` when you don't have to interact with swing. The oracle documentation says that `JApplet` is for Swing whereas `Applet` is for AWT. You can read the documentation  for `JApplet` here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JApplet.html And for `Applet` here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html

Answer (score 1):

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

This is not allowed even in a fully trusted applet.  Closing the frame would close the JVM that runs the applet that launched it.  That JVM might also be running other applets.

Look at it like this.  The web page that hosts an applet is like a guest, while the web page is a guest house.  For an applet to end the JVM is like the guest burning down the guest house while smashing out all the windows.

---

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```

Might 'work' (to not produce an `AccessControlException`), but really, no applet should be launching frames.  Use a `JDialog` instead.

As a general tip:  Ensure the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) is configured to show for applets & JWS apps.  If there is no output at the default level, raise it and try again.  Without the information contained in it, I doubt it would be possible to successfully develop an applet.

Comment: I didn't understood what you wrote in the general tip.
And what you say is that if I will put EXIT_ON_CLOSE and someone will close it, that will ruin the whole site in which the game is in?

Comment: Plus, I'll be happy if you will be able to send me a good site to learn JDialog, 'cause I didn't find one.

Comment: 1) What don't you understand about the tip?  Be specific as I don't intend writing a tutorial about it.  2) No, it won't ruin the entire site, since the security manager will prevent the action. 3) Add "JDialog tutorial" into your favorite search engine and follow the top link.

Comment: 1)I didn't understand anything you wrote in the tip. 3) I tried, but nothing was very clear.

Comment: *"I didn't understand anything you wrote in the tip."*  Give up programming.  You're obviously not cut out for it.

Comment: The fact I just got into it and don't understand some of the terms you used doesn't mean I'm not cut out for  it, just that I never heard them before...

Comment: *"just that I never heard them before..."*  And there you have it.  A programmer would have put 'unknown_term define' into a search engine and empowered themselves with new understanding, instead of what you did.  It isn't 'lack of knowledge' that makes you not fit to be a programmer, but more 'lack of initiative'.

Comment: I had the initiative to study programming in my hardest scholar year of high school so I don't have a complete lack of initiative. Other than that, English isn't my fist language, and also not the second, so it's a relatively hard for me to read the staff in Wikipedia, but I am ok with reading staff other people write on forums, and I really hope that with that we are done arguing.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Speed` class extends JFrame, but the only things that you set is `setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE)`, you should set at least se size of your `JFrame` with `setSize(width, height)` and set it visible with: `setVisible(true)`.
Another thing... i can't see where you added your `JFrame` to the `Main` class...
You should add it creating a new `Speed` object: `Speed objectname = new Speed()`

If i've understood correctly that was your problem.
I think you could read here to learn how to use the `JFrame`: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/206344-basic-gui-in-java-using-jframes/

Comment: I put the setVisible(true) in the init, dos'n setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE) and setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE) do the same thing?
BTW, I completely forgot about setSize(), so thanks.

Comment: *"you wrote `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` but it should be `JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE`"*  Either will work when the class `extends JFrame`.