# Deploying Java Web Application in Eclipse

Tags: java, python, eclipse, server

I've created a Java application in Eclipse that displays an ArcGIS map and needs to execute Python and some other external software like PowerWorld on my computer. I have purchased a domain name and intend to run it on my own server connected to the internet 24/7.

How do I embed and run my application on a website?

I've looked at Apache Tomcat tutorials but most of them involve creating simple text based webpages. Also, how do I move from localhost:8080 to my domain URL?

Comment: Unfortunately this is not really possible to do realistically nowadays with Java security issues requiring applet signing (self signed certificates aren't a viable solution if you want anyone to use your applet and browsers like chrome will not be supporting applets in the VERY near future). With that said, you can purchase a digital certificate which you can use for signing your jar files (assuming your "APPLICATION" is in-fact an "APPLET") once you reach that stage but from your post you said you created an application and not an applet so .... kind of bad news there.

Comment: My application opens up in a `JFrame`. So does this mean I have to write my code into an applet instead?

Comment: With regards to moving from local host - put your server code on your server. Run that server code. Assert required ports are open and probably some form of security. Alter client code to connect to server IP (or host name). Obviously when porting the server code to the server you tag along any dependencies like db stuff or whatever

Comment: With regards to your comment, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24344527 also, my advice: it sounds like you are a bit over your head and you will face major headaches even bothering with applets nowadays. Even if you get it to "work", it really won't ever "work" being that Java applets are becoming obsolete. Take it from someone worked in this industry for two years (specifically browser based Java applets), you should seek alternatives to applets.